# Web3.js get the "human readable value" balance for a contract and wallet

Tags: javascript, ethereum, web3js

i'm having a real brain fart atm. i have a simple getBalance function on a contract that accepts a wallet. this returns the balance, but as you know it's the BigNumber of the balance and doesnt factor in the decimals. So how do i turn:

806179086037007

into 806179.086037007

where the decimals for this given contract is 9.

```
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(minABI, contractName);
const decimals = await contract.methods.decimals().call();
const balance = await contract.methods
                .balanceOf(address)
                .call();
```

Ive tried varous solutions that i've found online and cant seem to get the value i want.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is not able to safely represent this large number as the native type `Number`, so `web3js` uses [BigNumber](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.8.0/web3-utils.html#bn) instead.

If you want to unsafely convert the larger number to native `Number` type with decimals, you can:

1. Convert it to `String`
2. Add the decimal point
3. Use the native function [parseFloat()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number_parsefloat.asp)

But be aware that it might cause rounding errors, as JS works with numbers slightly differently in different browsers and their versions / NodeJS versions / processor architectures / etc.

```
const balance = new web3.utils.BN("806179086037007");
const decimals = 9;

const balanceString = balance.toString();

// builds the String "806179.086037007"
const balanceStringWithDecimalPoint = [
    balanceString.slice(0, balanceString.length - decimals), 
    ".",
    balanceString.slice(balanceString.length - decimals)
].join("");


const nativeNumberUnsafe = Number.parseFloat(balanceStringWithDecimalPoint);
console.log(nativeNumberUnsafe);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are open to using [ethers.io library](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/getting-started/#getting-started--contracts), here is a simple example to achieve this:

```
// The Contract object
const daiContract = new ethers.Contract(daiAddress, daiAbi, provider);

// Get the balance of an address
balance = await daiContract.balanceOf(userAddress)
// { BigNumber: "6026189439794538201631" }

// Format the DAI for displaying to the user
ethers.utils.formatUnits(balance, 18)
// '6026.189439794538201631'
```

The `formatUnits` function accepts the balance in `BigNumber` and number of decimals, so in your case you need to pass `9` instead of `18`